# In a for loop in python 3.x are objects changed to immutable?

Tags: python, c++, python-3.x

In my code pasted bellow (which is python 3 code) I expected the for loop to change the original objects (ie I expected NSTEPx to have been changed by the for loop).  Since lists and arrays are mutable I should have edited the object by referring to it by the variable "data". However, after this code was run, and I called NSTEPx, it was not changed. Can someone explain why this is? I come from a background of C++ and the idea of mutable and immutable objects is something that I am only recently understanding the nuances of, or so I thought.

Here is the code:

```
NSTEPx = np.array(NSTEPx)
TIMEx = np.array(TIMEx)
TEMPx = np.array(TEMPx)
PRESSx = np.array(PRESSx)
Etotx = np.array(Etotx)
EKtotx = np.array(EKtotx)
EPtotx = np.array(EPtotx)
VOLUMEx = np.array(VOLUMEx)
alldata = [NSTEPx,TIMEx,TEMPx, PRESSx, Etotx, EKtotx, EPtotx]
for data in alldata:
    temp = data[1001:-1]
    data = np.insert(data,0,temp)
    data = np.delete(data,np.s_[1001:-1])
```

Comment: `data` is *new variable binding*; re-assigning to it *has no effect on what it previously 'named' or evaluated to*. This works the exact same way as *any* variable assignment or argument-cum-parameter passed to a function. There is *no* 'change' that occurs.

Comment: From a C++ perspective, `data` is a `T*`-typed variable and not a `T&`-typed variable; so it does *not* have C++ reference-assignment semantics. Furthermore, there is *no* equivalent to a C++ `T`-typed variable in Python and thus no copy-constructor semantics. With this in mind, the `.` operator in Python functions equivalently to the C++ `->` operator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python has **no** assignment! `data = value` is strictly a *binding* operation, not an assignment. This is really different then in eg C++

A Python variable is like a label, or a yellow sticky note: you can put it on *something* or move it to something else; it does not (**never**) change the *thing* (object) it is one.
The =-operator does move the label; it "binds" it. Although we usually say *assign*, it is really not the assign of C. (Where it is basically is a memory address)

To change a value is Python, you need a method: `aLabel.do_update()`, will (typically) change *self*, the object itself.
Note `aList[....]` is a method!

So, to change you data: change it (sec). Do not put a other label on it, nor put the existing label on other data!

Hope this explains you question

Comment: This is very helpful thank you! The idea of binding vs assigning is very different from C++. So in this case is there a way to change all the arrays from a loop or do I need to do this edit to each array individually?

Comment: For delete and insert use {data.} style instead of {np.} : then the assign is not needed as the data(object) itself is changed. Try this for the selection too. As I have no NP handy study that detail yourself

Answer (score 2):

In your loop, `data` refers to an array (some object). The object referred to is mutable. The variable `data` can be changed as well to refer to something else, but that won't change what's in `alldata` (values that refer to objects) or the variables whose contents you implicitly copied to construct `alldata`. Hence, all you change is a local variable (implicitly copied from `alldata`) to refer to a newly created array. Any other referring values are unchanged and still refer to the old array.